# Is there a better way to describe statistical "chance" on TV?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

Something I've noticed a lot on TV is hosts/announcers using statistics incorrectly by converting past performances into present odds.  For instance:

- A football announcer says a kicker has "a 16% chance" of making a kick from the 61-yard line.
- A host in a battle royale competition says each of the last four competitors has "a 25% chance" of being the winner.

This clearly cannot be correct from the point of view of statistics.  In the case of kicker, surely the announcer means that of all the kicks from the 61-yard line, only 16% have been good -- which is relevant to the current situtation but there are clearly other factors involved.  In the case of the battle royale, one person has a 100% chance, and the other three have a 0% chance.

This is a post about math and not word choice though so my question is this: Is there a specific way to compute/represent what the odds are at that given moment?  I'm thinking through a Bayesian representation of the most relevant factors involved.

In the case of the kicker, I figure there's the ability of the individual kicker to factor in as well as factors like wind speeds, the abilities of the snapper and holder, home vs. away, etc.  It seems it would be a similar analysis for the battle royale although obviously, the relevant factors under consideration will be different.

How would such a factor be computed?  By simply multiplying the odds of each contributing factor together?  1-the Baysean times everything else?  Or something else I'm not considering?

I get this change is unlikely to happen, but if it could, and did, what would it look like, as math?

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  It's hard to know what precise factors go into a moment like that.  Professional gamblers certainly keep track of a lot more factors then the simple "how often does this play succeed" statistic, but it's not a simple matter.

Comment: The are taking a "prior" distribution based on the past. This is common, typical and probably the best thing you can do.

Comment: @lulu, what I'm looking for how is the "not a simple matter" part.  No way it's gonna happen, but I'm interested in if it did, what might it look like?

Comment: As you suggest, you come up with a list of what you think are probably the key factors driving this play. Is this kicker exceptional one way or the other? Is it raining?  Is it cold?  Is the center on top of things?  Is the opposing defense likely to rush, and so on.  Then you estimate (somehow) how these things will alter the generic probabilitiy.

Comment: Your second bullet point does not appear to be a case of converting path performances into present odds. It is instead a case of assuming a uniform probability distribution.

Comment: There's a reason statisticians like baseball best.  You can isolate individual performances much better than in other sports.  Still messy.

Comment: You ask what might [a rigorous statistical analysis] look like? Well you'd collect a lot of past data and then make a judgment call to decide to the criteria you are going to base your analysis on. E.g., in the football example, you might decide to make your criteria be who the kicker is (or which team he plays for, or who coached him or ...) and which lines the kick was from. You then have a well-defined statistical problem. How valid the results of the statistical analysis are depends on whether you chose a good set of criteria: something you could refine over time.

Comment: "In the case of the battle royale, one person has a 100% chance, and the other three have a 0% chance."  Only if you can predict the result almost surely.  Or after it has finished

Comment: @LeeMosher you are exactly right, and that's the part where "language" comes into it.  Surely that's not what the host means to say, but the audience knows what he means and doesn't really care -- if they even wonder -- that it's incorrect.  Which is why I'm a lot more interested in the math.

Comment: @Henry, yes, but even if you can't they clearly can't all possibly have the exact same chance.

Comment: People who downvote I do which you would say why, but we live in an imperfect world.  @RobArthan I think you have the comment closest to what I'm looking for, if you'd like to turn it into an answer and claim the points.

Comment: I've added another example to my comment and posted it as an answer. I also upvoted the question.

Comment: Pretty sure I provided context with the "On TV" example.  Not sure who closed it but would you mind expanding on the reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask what might [a rigorous statistical analysis] look like? Well you'd collect a lot of past data and then make a judgment call to decide to the criteria you are going to base your analysis on. E.g., in the football example, you might decide to make your criteria be who the kicker is (or which team he plays for, or who coached him or ...) and which lines the kick was from. You then have a well-defined statistical problem. How valid the results of the statistical analysis are depends on whether you chose a good set of criteria: something you could refine over time.

Another example is weather forecasting. I believe the meteorologists come up with their percentage probabilities of rain say, by using past data to create a statistical model of how rain-bearing clouds spread or shrink as they move through the atmosphere. So based on present data about cloud coverage and wind speeds they can estimate for a given area of the earth the percentage of that area that will be covered by rain-bearing clouds at some time in the future. The forecast for my local area for tomorrow at 14:00 is 63%, meaning that their model predicts that 63% of the area will be covered by rain-bearing clouds. I.e., if you pick a random point in the area there is a 63% chance that it will be raining at that point. These predictions (at least in the UK) tend to be pretty accurate these days (and you can see what's going on on the day via weather radar) - so I imagine that there has been a great deal of refinement and that many more complex criteria than the ones I have mentioned are taken into account.